# How can I write a script that will read other scripts and record their processes?

Tags: powershell

I have a folder of scripts that are being used for my company, and I need to know what each script does. I am trying to write a script in power shell that will record what each script does into a csv file.

I am a beginner in Powershell and am still learning so I apologize if I am being unclear.

I know that each of these scripts basic function is to map drives to a users computer, but there are too many to go through manually, any advice would be appreciated!

EDIT: Most of them are bat with a couple of vbs too. I want to record what drives are being mapped.

EDIT 2: I have now written my own script that looks like this :

```
    Set-location z:\
    get-Childitem "z:\Test"|
    Foreach-object{
        $filename = $_.Fullname
        Get-content $filename|
           foreach-object {
            if ($_ -match "echo off") {
                Write-output "$($filename): $_" | select-object $_ $filename 
    | export-csv "test.csv" -notypeinformation
            }
        }
    }
```

I am having trouble exporting the data into a csv file as the error "A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'z:\Test\Test1.bat'"

Comment: What kind of scripts are they (PowerShell, VBScript, etc.)? What type of operation do you want to record (a type of command in the script, or what it touches on the file system/registry, etc)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way will be string parsing: look for the commands that map the drives. That's `net use` for bat files, or `MapNetworkDrive` in VBS. So look for those lines.

This will look through all the files in a folder and output the filename and the content of the line wherever it finds those lines:

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\Scripts" | 
Foreach-Object {
    $filename = $_.FullName
    Get-Content $filename |
    Foreach-Object {
        if ($_ -match "net use" -or $_ -match "MapNetworkDrive") {
            Write-Output "$($filename): $_"
        }
    }
}
```

That will not likely be exactly what you need, but it should get you started.